# Output an ISO 8601 string

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

How do we create a date/time in a specific timezone and output [a short ISO 8601 date/time with offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)? For instance, 5 PM Pacific Standard Time on 08 September 2015 must look like this:

```
2015-09-08T17:00:00-07:00
```

Here is my current attempt.

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1_Nodatime
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Log(string x) => Console.WriteLine(x);
        public static void Read() => Console.ReadLine();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var localDateTime = new LocalDateTime(2015, 09, 08, 17, 0);
            var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("America/Vancouver");
            var zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(zone);
            Log(zonedDateTime.ToOffsetDateTime().ToString());
            Read();
        }
    }
}
```

This works, though seems like too many steps.

1. Create a `LocalDateTime`
2. Create a `DateTimeZone`
3. Convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`
4. Convert the `ZonedDateTime` to an `OffsetDateTime`

How do we do it with fewer steps?

Comment: Keep in mind that Noda Time's API is intentionally verbose to keep you from making assumptions or relying on defaults.  You can read more on the design philosophy [here](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/design.html).

Comment: You don't need to convert it to an `OffsetDateTime`. You can format a `ZonedDatetime` directly to include the offset. But you shouldn't expect an offset for a `LocalDateTime` - after all, it doesn't *have* one. "5 PM Pacific Standard Time on 08 September 2015" is in a particular time zone - although it's not clear exactly which one you mean, as most Pacific time zones would be in Pacific *Daylight* Time rather than Pacific *Standard* Time on September 8th.

Comment: Please try to avoid changing the requirements in the question - first you wanted the offset to be represented as "-07:00", then "-07". Those formats will obviously have different answers... please pick which you want, and stick to it, to avoid having answers which don't match the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for the feedback. I did change the requirements in my question after Jason had already typed up a good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the comments of the question, you only need a `ZonedDateTime` in order to achieve your desired formatting (no need for the `OffsetDateTime`). The format string passes the "general" offset pattern so that the minutes should be included ("medium format") only if the offset has minutes.

```
zonedDateTime.ToString(
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sso<g>", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

For brevity, here are the available offset patterns documented:

> - f: Full format, displaying all information including fractional seconds. Typical pattern text: +HH:mm:ss.fff
> - l: Long format, displaying information down to the second. Typical pattern text: +HH:mm:ss
> - m: Medium format, displaying information down to the minute. Typical pattern text: +HH:mm
> - s: Short format, displaying information down to the hour. Typical pattern text: +HH
> - g: General pattern. Formatting depends on the value passed in:
>
>   - If the offset has fractional seconds, the full format is used; otherwise
>   - If the offset has seconds, the long format is used; otherwise
>   - If the offset has minutes, the medium format is used; otherwise
>   - The short format is used When parsing, the other standard format patterns are tried one at a time. This is the default format pattern.
> - G: As g, but using Z for an offset of 0, as if it were Z-prefixed.

Source: http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/offset-patterns.html

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

With the original request to format as ISO-8601 always showing the trailing minutes, you can use the custom format string below. By default, it meets ISO-8601 standards which does not require the trailing ":00". However, you can pass an offset pattern to force the formatting you are wanting:

```
zonedDateTime.ToString(
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sso<m>", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Source: http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/offset-patterns.html

**UPDATE TO SHORTEN CODE**

If you're just looking to shorten code, you can always wrap the code in a helper method - possibly even as a static extension method.

```
public static class NodaTimeHelpers
{
    public static Lazy<DateTimeZone> Zone = new Lazy<DateTimeZone>(
        () => DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("America/Vancouver"));
    public static string ToStringWithOffset(this LocalDateTime localDateTime)
    {
        if (localDateTime == null)
            return "";
        var zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(Zone.Value);
        return zonedDateTime.ToString(
            "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sso<g>",
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

This allows your local date time object to convert to string very easily:

```
localDateTime.ToStringWithOffset();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you can pass an offset pattern..." How do we do that?

Comment: The "o<m>" part is the offset pattern. By default, a ToString() uses o<G> (general pattern) which does the "-07" instead of the "-07:00" you are looking for when there are no minutes in the offset. The link below the sample code shows other standard offset patterns that you can select . Your requirement is met by changing from "o<g>" to "o<m>"  for medium format to always show minutes in the offset.

Comment: Added an update to help shorten your code with the desired formatting.

Comment: +1 for the `o<m>` pattern, but why introduce `Lazy<T>`?  Assigning a default zone seems strange, but if you're going to do that, you can just get it directly.  Also you can use an indexer instead of `GetZoneOrNull` for shorter code.

Comment: Added `Lazy<T>` to prevent running code until it was used. In reality, the impact here is so negligible it's pointless, but I've developed a habit (not already the best) in helper classes using `Lazy<T>` since as the helper classes have grown, I wanted to minimize the overhead of the class based on how it's used.

Comment: The OP has now changed their desired output - pretty unfriendly in terms of SO behaviour in my view, but it's probably worth changing your answer to match it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ouch. Thank you for the feedback. I did change my question.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I have updated the answer to match the change.  I had missed the changed format, but I left both as an example and expanded a bit more on the formatting options based on the docs.